# ¿Cómo controlar los inicios de sesión?

Tags: php, mysql, php7

estoy realizando una validación en mi pagina, de tal modo que cuando copien la URL los mande directamente al login, el problema que si ingreso los usuarios y contraseñas correctamente me manda al login, no se que estoy validando de manera errónea.

```js
<?php
session_start();
require("conexion.php");
$usu    = $_POST["txtusuario"];
$pass   = $_POST["txtpassword"];

$queryusuario = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario ='$usu' and pass = '$pass'");
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryusuario);
$encontrados = mysqli_num_rows($queryusuario);

if ($encontrados >= 1){
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $fila['usuario'];
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $fila['pass'];
    $_SESSION['nivel'] = $fila['nivel'];
    if ($_SESSION['nivel']==1){
        header('Location:pag_admin.php');   
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['nivel']==2){
        header('Location:pag_user.php');    
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['nivel']==3){
        header('Location:panel_usuario.php');   
    }
}
else{
    header('Location:login.php');
}

?>
```

[image: Pagina a prorteger]

Comment: Según entendí, si el usuario inicia sesión de manera correcta, este te dirige al **login.php**, con eso quiere decir que nunca entra en tu ```if ($encontrados >= 1){ }``` ¿estás seguro que obtienes datos? si haces un ```var_dump($fila);``` después de ```$fila``` que te imprime como resultado. Te aconsejo también que encriptas tus contraseñas a guardar en tu Base de Datos con ```password_hash()```

Comment: Como dice @masterguro es un ciclo repititivo que haces, el script valida y envia al url correcto pero una vez ahi esta redireccionado a que envie a index.php, solo hara el proceso si es nivel 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero verifica el valor que devulve  la varaible  `$encontrado` esto lo puedes hacer facilmente  agegando la siguiente linea de codigo abajo que la declaracion y  asignacion.

```html
$encontrados = mysqli_num_rows($queryusuario);
var_dump($encontrados); 
//esto lo agregas para que puedas ver el valor y no te redirija
die();
```

Si el valor que se imprime es `0` Tienes un problema con el query

si el valor es `> 1` el usuario se encontro  entonces tiene un problema en los archivos donde rediriges.

Si el nivel es `1`  lo rediriges a `pag_admin.php`  pero en esa pagina tienes la siguiente validacion.

```
if ($_SESSION['nivel']!=3){
    header('Location:index.php');   
}
```

La cual impide que el usaurio con nivel diferende de `3`  acceda. Cambia esta validacion en `pag_admin.php` por :

```
if ($_SESSION['nivel']!=1){
    header('Location:index.php');   
}
```

**Consejos que no has pedido**

1 .Para que tu codigo sea mas legible y  mas corto sin tanto anidamiento de `if` `else`
puedes cambiar un poco el codigo por el siguiente

```html
if ($encontrados == 0) header('Location:login.php');

$_SESSION['usuario'] = $fila['usuario'];
$_SESSION['pass'] = $fila['pass'];
$_SESSION['nivel'] = $fila['nivel'];
   
 //redirecciones segun nivel de usuario
if($_SESSION['nivel']==1)  header('Location:pag_admin.php');   
if($_SESSION['nivel']==2)  header('Location:pag_user.php');    
if($_SESSION['nivel']==3)  header('Location:panel_usuario.php');
```

2. Este tipo de consulta a la base de datos es suceptible a inyecciones sql

```html
SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario ='$usu' and pass = '$pass'"
```

Deberias sanitizar los valores del `$_POST`  o en su defecto utilizar `senetencias prepardas`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya funciono, gracias por el consejo, tambien quisiera saber de que manera podría mejorar este tipo de consulta

SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario ='$usu' and pass = '$pass'"

Comment: Es curioso como has editado tu respuesta, agregando mi respuesta en la tuya sin tan siquiera mencionarlo. En fin, "por sus acciones los conocereis".

Answer (score 2):

Aparte de los comentarios, y basándome solo en lo que aparece en tu pregunta, una vez la consulta es válida, haces esto:

```
if ($_SESSION['nivel']==1){
    header('Location:pag_admin.php');   
}
```

por lo tanto, si el usuario es de nivel 1 será redirigido a la página `pag_admin.php`.

Pero lo curioso es lo que haces después dentro de ese archivo **pag_admin.php** (que se corresponde con la captura de pantalla):

```
if ($_SESSION['nivel']!=3){
    header('Location:index.php');   
}
```

Es decir, un usuario con nivel 1 de admin consigue identificarse correctamente y es redirigido a *pag_admin.php*, **pero** dentro de `pag_admin.php` el código vuelve a verificar su nivel, y como este es distinto de **3**, lo manda de nuevo al **index.php**.  De este modo el admin nunca llega a cargar la página de su panel.

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es esto en su lugar para evitar esta incoherencia:

```
if ($_SESSION['nivel']!=1){
    header('Location:index.php');   
}
```

Eso es lo único que he podido deducir del código que has puesto, por lo tanto desconozco que ocurre en los otros niveles y las otras páginas porque sus códigos no estan en la pregunta, pero imagino que quizás también tienen el mismo problema.